# jQuery scrollTo function doesn't seem to work anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

and

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//  variable to keep track of menu state
var menuToggle = 0;

$(".menu-popup-button").click(function(){
  $(".menu-popup-button").toggleClass( "active" );
  $(".main-menu-wrapper").toggle();
  if (menuToggle == 0) {
    $('body').scrollTo('90px');
    menuToggle = 1;
  }
  else {
    menuToggle = 0;
    $(".main-menu-wrapper").toggle();
    $(".menu-popup-button").toggleClass( "active" );
    $('body').scrollTo('0px');
  }
});
});
```

What am I missing this time?

Comment: Uh well this is embarrassing. Nevermind. Should I delete or?

Comment: What is the window height ?

Comment: Uh, this was used to scroll on a mobile display to show the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `scrollTop` not scrollTo

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     //  variable to keep track of menu state
var menuToggle = 0;

$(".menu-popup-button").click(function(){
  $(".menu-popup-button").toggleClass( "active" );
    $(".main-menu-wrapper").toggle();
    if (menuToggle == 0) {
      $('body').scrollTop(90);
      menuToggle = 1;
    }
    else {
      menuToggle = 0;
      $(".main-menu-wrapper").toggle();
      $(".menu-popup-button").toggleClass( "active" );
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
    }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`window.scrollTo(90,0);`

instead of

`$('body').scrollTo('90px');`

*Note : window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos);*

Happy Coding :)